# C++ template specialization changes constexpr rules?

Tags: c++, templates

I am using g++ (GCC) 11.2.0.

The following piece of code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<int size>
constexpr std::vector<int> get_vector() {
        return std::vector<int> (size);
}

int main() {
        std::cout << get_vector<5>().size() << std::endl;
}
```

compiles successfully and outputs `5` when executed. Just as I expected.

However, if I add specialization

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<int size>
constexpr std::vector<int> get_vector() {
        return std::vector<int> (size);
}

template<>
constexpr std::vector<int> get_vector<2>() {
        return std::vector<int> (2);
}

int main() {
        std::cout << get_vector<5>().size() << std::endl;
}
```

it fails to compile and produces the error

```
another.cpp: In function ‘constexpr std::vector<int> get_vector() [with int size = 2]’:
another.cpp:10:28: error: invalid return type ‘std::vector<int>’ of ‘constexpr’ function ‘constexpr std::vector<int> get_vector() [with int size = 2]’
   10 | constexpr std::vector<int> get_vector<2>() {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/vector:67,
                 from another.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:389:11: note: ‘std::vector<int>’ is not literal because:
  389 |     class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:389:11: note:   ‘std::vector<int>’ has a non-trivial destructor
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) you will find out that gcc supports `constexpr std::vector` from version 12. As you tell us you use gcc 11.2 it simply is not implemented in the library.

You can see it working as expected on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/evdK1KdnG) with trunk versions of gcc and clang. For gcc it will be part of gcc 12.x versions.

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect it to be related to the compiler itself. What does standard say about this? Are vectors as constexpr return types just gcc's extension or does gcc11 not fully satisfy the standard?

Comment: @Kolay.Ne constexpr std::vector is part of C++20 and not an extension. It is not part of the compiler but part of the library which will be provided with the compiler. Yes, gcc 11 did not fully support C++20. If you take a look into the linked "compiler support" table, you will find out the version numbers vs. feature list of given c++ standard. As already mentioned, the constexpr std::vector is implemented first within gcc 12 which is currently not released ( yet ).